# Take the distinct values based on the most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to take the distinct results based on the most recent date. If my id field has decimals then i want the numbers after the decimal point to be truncated. my id field is in ntext format.

Input:

| name | id | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 12/25/2020 | 12/15/2021 |
| b | 3R | 10/08/2019 | 11/18/2019 |
| ab | 2.0 | 12/26/2020 | 12/16/2021 |
| c | 4 | 01/11/2018 | 10/06/2019 |
| ck | 4.4 | 04/01/2020 | 04/05/2021 |
| ad | 2.999 | 04/02/2021 | 04/05/2021 |

Output:

| name | id | date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ad | 2 | 04/02/2021 | 04/05/2021 |
| b | 3R | 10/08/2019 | 11/18/2019 |
| ck | 4 | 04/01/2020 | 04/05/2021 |

I tried stripping all the nums after the decimal point but that did not work.

```
substring('2.2', 0 , charindex('.','2.2'))
```

Edit: My ID field contains alphabets too.

Comment: Please provide your full query.

Comment: i tried but i got stuck at stripping the decimal and non decimals ids also i got stuck while picking up the most recent date per id.

Comment: ntext has been deprecated since 2005. why are you using it now? The [round() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can truncate - which seems to be what you need if you can safely (perhaps unlikely) assume your column contains valid numeric values.

Comment: May CAST(id as int) help you in that conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how you can do it, I assumed id is type decimal or number

```
select * from 
   (
    select * , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id - id % 1 order by date1 desc) rn
    from yourtable
   )
where rn = 1
```

if id is string then just cast it as int:

```
select name,convert(numeric(38, 0), id) id , date1, date2 from 
   (
    select * , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by convert(numeric(38, 0), id) as int) order by date1 desc) rn
    from yourtable
    where isnumeric(id) = 1
   )
where rn = 1
```

if you want to include non numeric as well :

```
select name,convert(numeric(38, 0), id) id , date1, date2 from 
   (
    select * , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by case when isnumeric(id) = 1 then convert(numeric(38, 0), id) else id end order by date1 desc) rn
    from yourtable     
   )
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Hey thank! but it says "conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int"

Comment: hmm.. do you have any non numeric values in id column ?

Comment: there is one id which is like " G566 006"

Comment: then I assume you want to filter them out , see my updated asnwer

Comment: I appreiciate your help but i'm still facing the error " conversion failed converting nvarchar '555.000' to data type int.

Comment: taking a bit from @Gordon's answer, convert(numeric(38, 0), id). I'm able to run the query without errors but the problem is the decimal values remains without getting them truncated.

Comment: then just show the converted id , see updated answer , thanks to gordon

Comment: awesome!! can we get rid of the isnumeric from the query? i might have some values with alphabets in i and i would prefer to have it

Comment: @New_here , no then convert will fail

Comment: :-( i cannot afford that. Is there any way to have alpha too without getting the rest hampered?

Comment: well that's another problem , based on your question this is the solution , but if there is more to it , you should include it into your question

Comment: see my third solution , hopefully that's the answer

Comment: Man it didn't work but i got to the soln with your ans. Appreciate it!! Bless you mate

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest converting to a numeric:

```
select convert(numeric(38, 0), id)
```

You might really want `try_convert()` if you have invalid numbers in the column.

If it a string, you can also get everything up to the first `'.'` using string functions:

```
select left(id, charindex('.', id + '.') - 1)
```

Note the `+ '.'`.  That prevents any errors when there are no decimal points.

Comment: Thx Gordon, this still gives me decimal values " 988.00". I want to get rid of the trailing values after the decimal

Comment: @New_here . . . I tweaked the second, but both work exactly as you intend:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e00e8d9aaecf997e4d17dc761713937b.